# Query set too many objects to unpack expected(2) in django templateView

Tags: django

I have written a view to show open, completed, accepted and closed tickets on dashboard on clicking which goes into particular url to display the tickets accordingly and am switching the templates according to their status, I am querying the ticket status and I get the following error

> Too many objects to unpack (expected 2)

**models.py**

```
class Modes(models.Model):
```

Comment: the edit that you suggested in my answer was not good because inside the list you put `'c','c'` but that is not good it is better to make some differences that's why i changed it to `'c','cl'` for `completed and closed` see my edit for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to this query...

```
Ticket.objects.filter('status')
```

You should specify something like:

```
if Ticket.objects.filter(status='Opened'):
    template_name = 'app/open_tickets.html')
```

Also please check the logic. Above query makes no sense in get_template_name... You should be getting one template according to request. So if request is for 'opened' then you should get template only for 'opened'.

Suppose if you want to get for 'opened' you need to pass it in query and do this:

```
if self.request.GET.get('status', '') == 'Opened':
    template_name = 'app/open_tickets.html')
```

Comment: `self.request.GET.get('status', '')` updated the answer... please check...

Comment: @乂TØXIC乂 does any user can have more tickets `(created_by)` ?

Comment: @乂TØXIC乂 are you using this  `http://<my_url>/?status='your-status-here'` in your url ? show me your url that you are using because this answer i think is correct.

Comment: @乂TØXIC乂 i can do want you but using function based_view ,is it okay ?

Comment: @乂TØXIC乂 i have posted an answer try it.it is not at all redundant it is just one function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def show(request,status):
    if status.title() in ['O','A,'C','Cl']:

        if status.title() == 'O':
            models = Model.objects.filter(status='O')
        else:
           models = Model.objects.filter(status=status.title(),accepted_by=request.user)
        templates = {'O':'p/op.html','A':'p/d.html','C':'p/pp.html','Cl:'a.html'}
        return render(request,templates[status.title()],{'tickets':tickets})
```

inside your urls.py

`path('models/<str:status>/',views.show,name='show')`